# User Journey Map

Tags: design, user-centered-design, maps

I am designing a mobile app. For that I interviewed many users and I created 4 Personas. Each Persona reflects unique characteristics, motivations and goals. Now I am onto creating User Journey Map. My question is, "Should I make a separate user journey map for each Persona?"

Comment: ok so each user interview will have one deliverable of one user map but after that, when I see common pains, do I build a global map with common pains?

Answer (score 5):

The user journey map shows the screens the user interacts with, in chronological order. It may also include the user's thoughts, emotions, or choice points. Even if your personas go through similar sequences of steps in the app, there should be some important differences between their experiences. Therefore, you'd want a separate map for each one (though you might also find it's useful to have a single map that lets you compare / superimpose them).

If you're thinking you could represent two personas' journeys with similar or identical maps, that's diagnostic of a problem -- either your two personas aren't actually different, or you haven't fully explored how the personas' differences will affect their journeys, or your map isn't allowing you to represent those differences.